# Can't get to work $match & $group MongoDB Aggregation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

This is my code:

```
this.aggregate(
{
    $match: {
        measurer_code : parseInt(_measurer_code),
        user_code :parseInt(_user_code),
        time : {$gte : iDate, $lte : eDate}

    }
},
{
    $group:{
        sum: {$sum: "$value"},
        cant: {$sum: 1}
    }
},cb);
```

The collection has the following structure:

```
user_code : Number, 
measurer_code : Number, 
value : Number, 
time : Date
```

Returns undefined. But if i run only $match or only $group returns documents.

Someone can help me?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to define an `_id` for your `$group`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you group you have to specify how you want to group the data.

If you want count and sum across all the documents, you have to add `"_id":null` or `"_id":1` (any constant) in the `$group` document.  If you want to group by field "foo" you have to add `"_id":"$foo"` to the document.